# In signed apk not able to fetch data from couch database

Tags: android

My app uses sync gateway to fetch & save data into couchbase server bucket. The app works fine in unsinged apk. However, in signed apk sometimes the app is unable to read certain documents or maybe part of documents. I tried debugging the signed apk and it works fine in debug mode.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60426773/edit) to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://$SITEURL$/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Finally got solution, on same issue. I have refactored code. Added dealy to load data and then updated UI. It means In signed apk processing speed is too fast as compare to debug apk. Its only the reason its not loading all  data and UI.